# Auto reloading flask server on Docker

Tags: python, docker, flask

I want my flask server to detect changes in code and reload automatically.
I'm running this on docker container.
Whenever I change something, I have to build and up again the container. I have no idea where's wrong. This is my first time using flask.

Here's my tree

```
├── docker-compose.yml
└── web
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── app.py
    ├── crawler.py
    └── requirements.txt
```

and code(app.py)

```
from flask import Flask 
import requests
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello Flask!!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True, host = '0.0.0.0')
```

and docker-compose

```
version: '2'
services:

  web:
    build: ./web
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
     - ./web:/code
```

Please give me some advice. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I believe what you need to do is to watch [this thread](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/184) on github more closely. And you never put your command on how you run your docker

Comment: Please, post your docker-compose and I will see to adapt it

Comment: @Robert I added it. Please look into it and help me.

Comment: @James, does the below answer help you?

Comment: @Robert, Fortunately, yes. The problem was './web:/code'. I changed it to './web:/abb' and it works. But don't know why...

Comment: Not related to the question itself, but for newer versions, also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55271912/flask-cli-throws-oserror-errno-8-exec-format-error-when-run-through-docker.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Flask supports code reload when in debug mode as you've already done. The problem is that the application is running on a container and this isolates it from the real source code you are developing. Anyway, you can share the source between the running container and the host with volumes on your `docker-compose.yaml` like this:

Here is the `docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build: ./web
    ports: ['5000:5000']
    volumes: ['./web:/app']
```

And here the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:alpine

EXPOSE 5000

WORKDIR app

COPY * /app/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD python app.py
```

Comment: Could you explain the volumes, why the naming is that what you've provided?

Comment: @MattSom, volumes are the folders that you're going to bind from your machine to the container itself. I.e. the local folder is going to exist inside the container. 

If you follow the OP question and take a look at the file-tree structure, the source code is inside a folder named `web`. The `volumes` then is just sharing this folder into a new one called `app` inside the container. BTW, `app` because in the `Dockerfile` the default `WORKDIR` is `app` and everything is copied to `/app/` also (`volumes` in the docker-compose is going to take priority over the copied files).

Comment: It's nice to keep the `COPY * /app/` in the `Dockerfile` so the `Dockerfile` is self-contained apart from the docker-compose.

Comment: Thank you so much for the great explanation, you should add it to the answer imho. Thanks for the `Copy * /app/` comment as well. I had a react app and used `Copy . .` but hot realoding did not want to work. I went crazy for days but with this one it works!

Comment: Why are you EXPOSing port from Dockerfile if docker-compose.yaml is already exposing it?

Comment: @MáximaAlekz just to make the `Dockerfile` self-contained. I.e. you can `docker build...` and `docker run...` it manually and it still works without `docker-compose`

Answer (score 24):

I managed to achieve flask auto reload in docker using docker-compose with the following config:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build: ./web
    entrypoint:
      - flask
      - run
      - --host=0.0.0.0
    environment:
      FLASK_DEBUG: 1
      FLASK_APP: ./app.py
    ports: ['5000:5000']
    volumes: ['./web:/app']
```

You have to manually specify environment variables and entrypoint in the docker compose file in order to achieve auto reload.

Comment: perfect now we can finally ditch from the app.py: 
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug = True, host = '0.0.0.0')

Comment: is it correct you still need the `WORKDIR app
COPY * /app/` commands from lepsch ?

Comment: A bit late but no - you shouldn't need to as the `/app` is now a _mounted_ volume. Copying over the files is not necessary

Comment: could you describe how `volumes: ['./web:/app']` works please?

Comment: @MattSom By adding the volume, docker compose will sync the host folder with the container folder.

Comment: BTW if using Dockerfile use:
ENV FLASK_DEBUG=1

Answer (score 7):

Assuming your file structure is the below:

[image]

**Dockerfile: (note WORKING DIR)**

```
FROM python:3.6.5-slim
RUN mkdir -p /home/project/bottle
WORKDIR /home/project/bottle 
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --upgrade pip --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

**Docker Compose:**

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    container_name: web
    volumes:
      - './web:/home/project/bottle/'  <== Local Folder:WORKDIR
    build: ./web
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me. This trick is to make sure you mount your local code folder to the WORKDIR you've set in the Dockerfile. For me that was `WORKDIR=/home/app` so under volumes in the docker-compose file I needed to mount like this: ``- ./app:/home/app`

Answer (score 1):

This is my example:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  local-development:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfiles/development.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
```

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return "hello world"


if __name__ in "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, debug=True)
```

`debug=True` enables Flask to change as your code changes.

Docker already plugs into your fs events to change the code "in the container".

Comment: This does not show your file structure so not informative enough.

Answer (score 0):

If the compose is running different services (app and rq, for instance) you need to set up the volumes on both, or it won't work.