# Flask docker compose reload when changing source code?

Tags: python, docker, flask

I'm used to python reloading flask in debug mode automatically when changes have been detected in the source code. I started moving over to docker composer, I can't get it so that it reloads automatically in the container.

my dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 80
ENV NAME World
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

my docker compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    build: .
    ports:
     - "80:80"
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

Comment: How do you change the code **in the container**?

Comment: I don't change the code in the container, only in the source `app.py`, is that my mistake?

Comment: @RoyHolzem take a look at the accepted answer here: [Auto reloading flask server on Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342741/auto-reloading-flask-server-on-docker). It describes exactly this... *"The problem is that the application is running on a container and this isolates it from the real source code you are developing. Anyway, you can share the source between the running container and the host with `volumes` on your `docker-compose.yaml`"*.