# Error running auto reloading flask app on Docker

Tags: python, flask, docker-compose, uwsgi

I am setting up a flask development environment and want my flask server to detect changes in code and reload automatically.

My project structure is:

```
python-flask
    |--docker-compose.yml
    |--flask
    |   |--Dockerfile
    |   |--requirements.txt
    |   |--app.ini
    |   |--run.py
    |   |--app
    |       |--__init__.py
    |       |--app.py
    |--nginx
        |--Dockerfile
        |--nginx.conf
```

The code for **app.py**

```
import os
from flask import Flask, session, g

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    # Use os.getenv("key") to get environment variables
    app_name = os.getenv("APP_NAME")

    if app_name:
        return f"Hello from {app_name} running in a Docker container behind Nginx!"

    return "Hello from Flask"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Here is my **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  flask:
    build: ./flask
    container_name: flask
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./flask/app:/app
    environment:
      - APP_NAME=MyFlaskApp
    expose:
      - 8080
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

As mention in [Auto reloading flask server on Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342741/auto-reloading-flask-server-on-docker) I added `py-autoreload = 1` to my app.ini.  Here is my **app.ini**

```
[uwsgi]
wsgi-file = run.py
callable = app
socket = :8080
processes = 4
threads = 2
master = true
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
py-autoreload = 1
```

When I run `docker-compose up --build`, flask returns error:

```
Starting nginx ... done
Attaching to flask, nginx
flask    | realpath() of app.ini failed: No such file or directory [core/utils.c line 3654]
```

I am not sure how to fix this error.  I have tried changing `volume` in my docker-compose.yml to `./app:/app`, however the error persisted

Comment: Please post contents of `flask/Dockerfile`