# How do I hot-load a dockerized python app?

Tags: python, docker, flask

I am unable to get hot reload work for my python app. I did try other threads [Auto reloading flask server on Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342741/auto-reloading-flask-server-on-docker) too. Here's my code:

```
#docker-compose.yml
app:
  build: .
  command: python -u app.py
  ports:
    - "5000:5000"
  volumes:
    - .:/app
  links:
    - db
db:
  image: mongo:latest
  hostname: dstudio_mongodb
  environment:
    - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=dstudio_db
  ports:
    - 27017:27017
```

My docker file

```
FROM python:3.7
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I am using docker-compose up for now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch the ADD and WORKDIR statements, use `*` instead of `.`.
Also, delete the command statement in the docker-compose and add `CMD python -u app.py` to your Dockerfile.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7
WORKDIR /app
ADD * /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD python -u app.py
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
app:
  build: .
  ports:
    - "5000:5000"
  volumes:
    - .:/app
  links:
    - db
db:
  image: mongo:latest
  hostname: dstudio_mongodb
  environment:
    - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=dstudio_db
  ports:
    - 27017:27017
```

Comment: Thanks, Fabian. I tried switching the ADD and WORKDIR lines and added CMD line to the docker file, but the hot-load doesn't work still. Also, when I add 3.7 to the compose file, I get this error:  You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version. Either specify a supported version (e.g "2.2" or "3.3") and place your service definitions under the `services` key, or omit the `version` key and place your service definitions at the root of the file to use version 1.
For more on the Compose file format versions, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/