Flask debug not hot reloading in docker container
I am attempting to run a Flask server in a docker container with debug enabled so that I can hot reload during development and try out changes. Unfortunately the hot reload is not detecting changes even though I have verified the file has changed from within the container. My set up is as follows:
Host directory structure
|
|- Src
|   |- app.py
|
|- docker-compose.yaml
|- Dockerfile
|- requirements.txt

Requirements.txt
flask

Dockerfile
FROM python:3.11-slim

ENV DEBUG_COLOR=true

ENV PYTHONPATH=.

RUN mkdir /usr/local/app

WORKDIR /usr/local/app

COPY requirements.txt /usr/local/app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "app.py"]

docker-compose.yaml
services:

    test:
        build:
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
            context: .
        image: test:latest
        environment:
            - FLASK_DEBUG=1
        ports: ['3000:3000']
        volumes: [
            './src:/usr/local/app'
            ]
        command:
             python app.py

app.py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    print('GET /, was called.')
    return 'Hello world.'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', port = '3000')

I can kick this off from the command line using docker compose up and everything builds and runs as expected resulting in the output:
Attaching to test-1
test-1  |  * Serving Flask app 'app'
test-1  |  * Debug mode: on
test-1  | WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
test-1  |  * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
test-1  |  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:3000
test-1  |  * Running on http://172.18.0.2:3000
test-1  | Press CTRL+C to quit
test-1  |  * Restarting with stat
test-1  |  * Debugger is active!
test-1  |  * Debugger PIN: 582-087-710

From this I can see the debugger is running and it should be restarting with stat. I can then visit the served page at http://127.0.0.1:3000 and it serves the expected Hello world!. I can also attach to the running container and check the content of app.py using cat app.py.
If I then fire up an editor on the host and change the content of app.py, for example change the message returned to be:
    return 'Hello test world.'

I expect the debugger to detect the change and reload, however it does not do this. I can look at the content of app.py in the container I can see the code has changed, but visiting the URL I still get served Hello world!.
Note: this is unlike the issue in Auto reloading flask server on Docker where the code was copied into the container and volumes was not used to map the host src to the container directory.
Any suggestions on the step I am missing here are very welcome!

This question is similar to: Auto reloading flask server on Docker. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The issue in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342741/auto-reloading-flask-server-on-docker was they were using a COPY command and not then using a volume to map the host src directory to the container directory. This results in static container that is not related to the host environment, i.e. if you change the host code the code in the container remains the same, this is why I described attaching to the container to ensure this was working.

Based on your example, I changed the mounted path from /usr/local/app to /project, and set debug=True. Flask was then able to detect changes and hot-reload properly again.
app.py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    print('GET /, was called.')
    return 'Hello world.'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', port = '3000', debug=True)

Dockerfile
FROM python:3.11-slim

ENV DEBUG_COLOR=true

ENV PYTHONPATH=.

#RUN mkdir /usr/local/app

WORKDIR /project

COPY requirements.txt /project

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Declare it on either the `docker-compose.yml` or `Dockerfile`, don't need both.
# CMD ["python", "app.py"]

docker-compose.yml
services:
    test:
        build:
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
            context: .
        image: test:latest
        # Because it's not using command like `flask run` to launch the project, so it's not necessary either.
        #environment:
        #    - FLASK_DEBUG=1
        ports: ['3000:3000']
        volumes: [
            './src:/project'
            ]
        command:
             python app.py

After modifying above, rebuild and launch the project.
$ docker compose up --build

It’s quite strange. Despite setting debug=True or using docker compose --watch, hot-reloading still doesn’t work unless I change the mounted path from /usr/local/app to /project (which might be related to the system path or Flask's watchdog detection paths).
The /usr/local directory is often used for system-level installations, and file system events might not be properly propagated when mounting volumes there in a Docker container.

Thanks for looking at this, I agree this is strange. I was using /usr/local/app as in a production environment I deploy to that location, but then I only need the code to be static. Maybe there is a system service protecting the content or similar?

I believe that system service protection is less relevant. This is because changing the path to /var/local/app still works. I think it is more related to Flask's file change detection mechanism regarding reference paths, as both the default /usr and /usr/local directories contain a src folder. Using /usr/app or /usr/local/app will cause the hot-reload to fail. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any relevant references; I only have the experimental results. I hope they are helpful.
